# How to convert a series of if/else if/else if/ chain of relations into linear looping code

Tags: c++, vectorization, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I have the core of an algorithm that I want to convert from essentially a series of if/else if/else if/else i/ chain about 20 deep to a loop that could be done in linear fashion. The conditionals are simple with one of the 4 possibilities (A[i] < B[j]), (A[i] <= B[j]), (A[i] > B[j]), (A[i] >= B[j]). How can I convert all of them to a single conditional. For example the chain could be something like this.

```
if (A[i+0] <  B[j+0]) break
if (A[i+1] <= B[j+1]) break
if (A[i+2] >  B[j+2]) break
if (A[i+3] >= B[j+3]) break
if (A[i+4] >= B[j+4]) break
....
```

Each conditional could be 1 of 4 possible, but I want to convert them all into a single set of steps without a case so that it could be done in a loop (or possibly in parallel with vector intrinsics)

```
// Given a list R[n] of 4 possible relations loop over all the data
int result = 1;
for (i = 0; i < num_relations && result; ++i) {           
       // How do I convert this to linear code which does the equivalent of
       // (the value of R[n] and what relation it maps is flexible, this is an example)
       case (R[n]) {
          0 : result = A[i] <  B[i]; break;
          1 : result = A[i] <= B[i]; break;
          2 : result = A[i] >  B[i]; break;
          3 : result = A[i] >= B[i]; break;
       }
}
```

Some properties for (unsigned numbers) that can be possibly used are

```
(A > B) ^ 1 === (A <= B) ^ 0
```

Can the above be optimized to something better than

```
result = 1;
for (i = 0; i < num_relations && result; ++i) {           
   result = ((A[i] <  B[i]) && (R[i] == 0)) ||
            ((A[i] <= B[i]) && (R[i] == 1)) ||
            ((A[i] >  B[i]) && (R[i] == 2)) ||
            ((A[i] >= B[i]) && (R[i] == 3));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without vectorization, your `if()` sequence is as fast as it can get. In that case you must have one compare instruction per condition, you can't get around it (even though some machines can optimize the branches away except for one).

With vectorization, you can perform multiple comparisons in parallel, under the requirement that they are all in the same direction. But that can be achieved by transforming your input values:

```
int signs[] = {1, 1, -1, -1, -1, ...};
int equals[] = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, ...};
if (A[i+0] <  signs[0]*B[j+0] + equals[0]) break;
if (A[i+1] <  signs[1]*B[j+1] + equals[1]) break;
if (A[i+2] <  signs[2]*B[j+2] + equals[2]) break;
if (A[i+3] <  signs[3]*B[j+3] + equals[3]) break;
if (A[i+4] <  signs[4]*B[j+4] + equals[4]) break;
...
```

However, vectorization of this code should fail because the compiler is required not to load `A[i+1]` from memory before the first condition is evaluated and shown not to be fulfilled. So you need to make the condition evaluation nondependent on each other:

```
int signs[] = {1, 1, -1, -1, -1, ...};
int equals[] = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, ...};
int doBreak = 0;
doBreak |= (A[i+0] <  signs[0]*B[j+0] + equals[0]);
doBreak |= (A[i+1] <  signs[1]*B[j+1] + equals[1]);
doBreak |= (A[i+2] <  signs[2]*B[j+2] + equals[2]);
doBreak |= (A[i+3] <  signs[3]*B[j+3] + equals[3]);
doBreak |= (A[i+4] <  signs[4]*B[j+4] + equals[4]);
...
if(doBreak) break;
```

Now you are free to make a loop out of it.

Comment: I like where this one is going, since it opens up to the possibility of vectorization

Answer (score 1):

1. Create four helper function that meet the signature:

   ```
   bool (*)(int A, int B);

   bool isLess(int A, int B) { return A < B; }
   bool isLessOrEqual(int A, int B) { return A <= B; }
   bool isGreater(int A, int B) { return A > B; }
   bool isGreaterOrEqual(int A, int B) { return A >= B; }
   ```
2. Put them in an array.

   ```
   typedef bool (*CompareFunction)(int A, int B);
   CompareFunction functions[] = {isLess, isLessOrEqual, isGreater, isGreaterOrEqual};
   ```
3. Use the array of functions in the loop.

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < num_relations && result; ++i) {           
     result = functions[i](A[i], B[i]);
   }
   ```

Comment: Calling through a function pointer is a rather expensive operation. Assuming that the goal is performance, it's very unlikely to help here.

Comment: @duskwuff, Something I learned today. Can you provide some references I can look up? Thank.

Comment: 1 jump predictions vs 4 branch predictions... I would say function pointer win.

Comment: @Jarod42 You'd be wrong. Predicting through a function pointer call is very difficult. Many processors can't do it *at all*.

Comment: I am more than open to experimentation and can give this a try, but as pointed out the key is performance and straight linear code without jumps branches. Eventually leading to using vectorization so this can be done in parallel across N Relations

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of bitwise `AND`:

```
result = 1;
for (i = 0; i < num_relations && result; ++i) {           
    delta = A[i] - B[i];

    //  R[i] & 1 is true for 1 and 3
    //  R[i] & 2 is true for 2 and 3   
    if (delta == 0) {
        result = (R[i] & 1);
    }
    else  {
        //  exclusive or
        result = (delta < 0) ^ (R[i] & 2);
    }
}
```

The trick is to combine cases and thus reduce the number of relational operations.

Comment: this is exactly the kind of magic I am looking for. Not that R[i] value and the relation it maps to can be optimized for bitwise operations. I will check the math on this and get back to you